# Function to determine if a range of consecutive (positive) integers can be written as the sum of two (positive) composite-relatively prime integers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function, number-theory

I would like to have a function that determines whether every integer **n** in a range of consecutive positive integers from **a** to **b** (inclusive) can be written as the sum of two positive composite integers both relatively prime to **n**.

The function input and output should be of the form:

1. **function(a,b)** = FALSE, the highest integer in the range that failed the test is **c**
2. **function(a,b)** = TRUE, all integers in the range passed the test

**INPUT:**

For the input, the user just types two integers where 1 ≤ a < b.

- If the user types an invalid integer, there should be an error message like "invalid choice of integers".
- Something similar must happen if there's at least one missing value for the input.

**OUTPUT:**

The output of the function should start with the Boolean value FALSE if there's **at least one** integer **n**, in the range from **a** to **b**, that cannot be written as the sum of two (positive) composite integers both relatively prime to **n**.

The function should then output the highest of such integers that fails the test. The full output should be printed in the console using format (1) above: Boolean value FALSE + string of characters (as shown) + highest integer that failed the test.

On the other hand, the output of the function should start with the Boolean value TRUE if **each** integer **n** in the range of integers from **a** to **b** can be written as the sum of two (positive) composite integers both relatively prime to **n**. The full output should be printed in the console using format (2) above: Boolean value TRUE + string of characters (as shown).

**Example:**

Consider the range of integers (90,100) - that is, integers starting from 90 until 100.

100 = 49 + 51 (both composite and relatively prime to 100)

99 = 49 + 50 (both composite and relatively prime to 99)

98 = 33 + 65 (both composite and relatively prime to 98)

97 = 49 + 48 (both composite and relatively prime to 97)

*96 cannot be written as the sum of two relatively prime composite numbers*

95 = 49 + 46 (both composite and relatively prime to 95)

94 = 49 + 45 (both composite and relatively prime to 94)

93 = 49 + 44 (both composite and relatively prime to 93)

92 = 35 + 57 (both composite and relatively prime to 92)

91 = 45 + 46 (both composite and relatively prime to 91)

*90 cannot be written as the sum of two relatively prime composite numbers*

Hence

**function(90,100)** = FALSE, the highest integer in the range that failed the test is **96**

At least one integer in the range failed the test and so the function returns FALSE, to begin with. Even though both 90 and 96 failed the test, only 96 is displayed in the output as it has the highest value.

**function(91,95)** = TRUE, all integers in the range passed the test

Since every integer passed the test in the range (91,95) the function returns TRUE, to begin with.

**Extra information:**
I'm pretty much sure that this algorithm will involve some kind of For/While loops, potentially with some nested IF statements. But as I've stated in the comments below, I'm just not sure how to piece it all together to achieve what I aiming for.

Comment: This is a very interesting problem. What've you tried so far? What are the results you get?

Comment: As I'm not proficient in programming yet, I was limited to just doing a handful of examples manually. But of course there's only so much you can do without an efficient algorithm. I don't really know where to begin when it comes to an algorithm to test the conditions stated above. I've thought about for loops, while loops and so on but I can't really piece it together to achieve what I want.

Comment: Write what you can. Explain where you are stuck in specific terms. Like "I don't know how to repeat these operations for all the numbers from a to b" or "I don't know how to check if the user typed an invalid integer" or "I don't know how to tell if a number is composite", etc.

Comment: Also, you say "100 = 49 + 51 (both composite and relatively prime to 100)", but the statement is that the terms must be relatively prime to "integers from a to b respectively". In the example, a=90 and b=100, and 49 is not relatively prime to 91 (which is an integer between 90 and 100).

Comment: According to the function, each integer in the range must be the sum of at least one pair of composite numbers that are relatively prime to it. For example 91 has at least one such pair: 45 and 46 as stated above. On the other hand the integers 90 and 96 have no such pairs at all that satisfy the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your sequence of numbers which can't be written as a sum of 2 composite and relatively primes is **finite** -> http://oeis.org/A096076
And pretty small too.
Notice that if (and only if) a 2 numbers are coprime to each other <-> the sum is coprime to any of them.
for proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_are_Coprime_iff_Sum_is_Coprime_to_Both

so best solution would just check if the interval contains one of them, and if it does take the smallest one and return it

for more detail and information I've found a few stuff about it:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354215/not-the-sum-of-two-relatively-prime-composite-numbers
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1455165/numbers-as-sum-of-two-relatively-prime-composite-numbers

Comment: A096076 is for the two terms to be relatively prime to each other. The question is for the terms to be relatively prime to the sum.

Comment: if they're coprime to each other they're coprime to the sum -> https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Numbers_are_Coprime_iff_Sum_is_Coprime_to_Both

Comment: @JackRaBeat Yeah, I eventually figured that out. The equivalence may be worth calling out.